# Нормально ли задавать высоты тегам <html> и <body>?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Я ученик.
Cтолкнулся с неадекватным поведением в адаптивного элемента (в Хроме в режиме имитации смартфона). Вкратце, проблема видна, когда у его предка стоит правило `height: 100vh;`, если же вместо этого поставить ему и `<html>` и `<body>` высоты 100% - всё становится хорошо. В файрфоксе проблемы вовсе не вижу.

Это вообще нормально - ставить какую-либо высоту для `<html>` и `<body>`?

Comment: Действительно, любопытно.
А что по высотам `<html>` и `<body>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, и для html и для body тоже можно задавать разные css-правила, и высоту в том числе.

На будущее, когда возникнут очередные вопросы "А делают ли так в принципе?", подсмотрите ответы на них у профессионалов, например хотя бы здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоило обратить внимание, что тут, в отличие от вопроса height:100% стоит только у html

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я посмотрел и здесь и ещё на нескольких сайтах. Где-то установлена, где-то - нет. Я где-то услышал, что на тэги вешать правила - вообще большой грех. Вот и искал мнений живых людей.

Answer (score 3):

Aleksandr Shemetillo, посмотри мой пример и подумай, почему на данный момент фон не красный? Потом раскомментируй `/*height: 100%;*/` и фон станет красным... Но если `#wrapper` задать `height:` не в процентах, то он будет виден...  Это я к тому, что изначально у `body` нет высоты. Хочешь никогда не ошибаться, сделай себе привычку главный файл `css` начинай с этих строк ниже...

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но вы отвечаете не совсем на мой вопрос, а, скорее, на свою интерпретацию его. Пример мне понятен, но в моём случае было скорее так, приблизительно:
`html,
body {
  /* height: 100%; */
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}`. Как видите, "рост" у элемента всё же есть.

Правила из вашего ответа я тоже ставлю обычно, поскольку это удобно. Просто я не вполне уверен был, что это профессионально.

Comment: учи css и вполне будешь уверен...)

Answer (score 2):

Это нормально и часто оправдано. Если обратиться к спецификации, то там сказано, что свойство `height` может быть задано всем элементам за исключением non-replaced инлайновых элементов, ячеек таблиц и column groups. `<html>` и `<body>` это block-level элементы, так что `height` можно спокойно им задавать.

[Visual formatting model details](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)

> 'height'
>   Applies to:     all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups